# Run official Kinect SDK on iMac

Tags: windows, kinect

I would like to create my Kinect development environment and am contemplating using iMac as the box with Windows 7 installed as dual boot and/or parallels.

Has anyone tried this configuration earlier and does it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running Bootcamp(dual boot) works with windows 7/8 Parallels does not. 
I have a macpro 1,1 and a mac air both work with bootcamp(dual boot).

The only thing that could cause it not to work is the USB configuration. Kinect requires that it be connected to a USB host controller and not a hub. I believe all of the iMac's USB ports are host ports so I don't believe this to be an issue. If you use the Kinect Sensor Chooser control built into the WPFViewers sample app it will tell you if that particular problem arises (insufficient bandwidth).

Parallels will not work with the SDK at the time of this writing due to driver. Kinect is not an official USB device and the driver requires direct communication with the Kinect. I hoped that this would be resolved with the official Kinect for Windows hardware but alas it was not.

Comment: I am ok with it running on dual boot. The real question was whether this is possible and has someone tried it. Logically I do not see any issues with it, still I wanted to confirm Have you actually tried running Kinect with dual boot windows on Mac?

Comment: Yes I have and it works. "Running Bootcamp(dual boot) works with windows 7/8 Parallels does not. I have a macpro 1,1 and a mac air both work with bootcamp(dual boot)."

Comment: This all changed with V1.6. If you have the official Kinect for Windows sensor you can now run it in Parallels or VMWare Fusion

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look at native OSX Kinect development using OpenKinect

http://openkinect.org/wiki/Getting_Started

If you don't want to have to write all the image processing code yourself, and are working in C#, you could start with the Accord library:

http://accord-net.origo.ethz.ch/

Comment: The second link is dead. This appears to be the new location: http://accord-framework.net/  But I don't see anything about kinect for osx at this project. It describes itself as "Accord.NET provides statistical analysis, machine learning, image processing and computer vision methods for .NET applications."